# Android - playing html5 <video> in html code

Tags: android, html, video, webview

I know there are a lot of old discussion about this, but I am developing for new devices.

I want to use WebView to show html5 video in video tag. I want to use this for android devices 4.0+ or even 4.1+.

I do not want to change the WebView code a lot. Is it possible to show movie in WebView without opening some new views on top? Because most of the answers opened new view to play video? I need easy solution with as less as possible code corrections.

Any code or tutorial will be welcome.

**UPDATED**

manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.videoexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    >


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.videoexample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Main-file:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // load the customURL with the URL of the page you want to display
        String pageURL = "http://www.vongola-restavracija-izola.si/powzyLibrary1/video.html";
        webView.loadUrl(pageURL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I started working off https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/

Video works there. Make sure your video is compatible with android

Comment: How can I test if it is compatible? If it works in android default browser then it is compatible?

Comment: see http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/ and yes, if it works on default browser it should work inside a webview too. I personally stick with .mp4. Haven't had any of those who didn't work

Comment: This solution works, but for now I will try to find simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

the following is a snippet from an application I have for Android API15 and above that plays supported video types (.mp4 is the most reliable). It can serve content from a URL or created in-line (commented out).

If, with this, the video still won't play, can you post a link to a sample here so we can check if it's compatible.

You need the following in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and

```
<application
android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
.... />
```

and then the code:

```
package com.offbeatmammal.android.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // load the customURL with the URL of the page you want to display
    // String pageURL = "http://url/page.html";
    // webView.loadUrl(pageURL);

    String customHtml = "<html><head><title>Sample</title></head><body><video controls><source src='http://www.broken-links.com/tests/media/BigBuck.m4v'></video></body></html>";
    webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
}
}
```

Comment: I updated the code that I have and that is not working.

Comment: the issue is not the video, it seems to be that page. If you try the edited code above which now references the inline HTML and points to the m4v asset from the broken-links page it should play

Comment: Still nothink :( I also create two webpage ant try to load it but with no success: http://www.vongola-restavracija-izola.si/powzyLibrary1/video.html and http://www.vongola-restavracija-izola.si/powzyLibrary1/video1.html

Comment: I am using 4.0.3 android.

Comment: What device are you testing on? Just as an FYI video will not work in most emulator situations

Comment: FWIW using both your links (BBB and Minions) in my test page on Android 4.0.3, 4.2 and 4.4 devices are slow to load, but worked fine. Not sure what else to suggest at this point

Comment: I am using LG-e610, I will try some other devices and see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

set this in meanifeast.xml

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

**hardwareAccelerated** works in above 3.0. so you can play video in WebView.

refer this [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

Comment: I added this but it does not play video. I tryed on this example:http://broken-links.com/tests/video/  http://www.broken-links.com/2009/10/06/building-html5-video-controls-with-javascript/