# webview html5 video shows no video only audio

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to play `HTLM5` video within android `WebView` but I have recorded no success. The audio of the video plays but the video doesn't display. I have enabled `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the Manifest, I have used the `WebChromeClient` but still no success
I have followed examples here, e.g

-[Android - playing html5 <video> in html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756378/android-playing-html5-video-in-html-code)
-https://code.google.com/archive/p/html5webview/source/default/source

Please advise, Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
public class ExploreCourseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

HTML5WebView mWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://broken-links.com/tests/video/");
    }

    setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mWebView.stopLoading();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (mWebView.inCustomView()) {
            mWebView.hideCustomView();
            //  mWebView.goBack();
            //mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
}
```

**HTML5WebView.java**

```
public class HTML5WebView extends WebView {

private Context mContext;
private MyWebChromeClient                   mWebChromeClient;
private View mCustomView;
private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback  mCustomViewCallback;

private FrameLayout                         mContentView;
private FrameLayout                         mBrowserFrameLayout;
private FrameLayout                         mLayout;

static final String LOGTAG = "HTML5WebView";

private void init(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    Activity a = (Activity) mContext;

    mLayout = new FrameLayout(context);

    mBrowserFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(R.layout.custom_screen, null);
    mContentView = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_content);
    mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

    mLayout.addView(mBrowserFrameLayout, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);

    // Configure the webview
    WebSettings s = getSettings();
    s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    //  s.setSavePassword(true);
    s.setSaveFormData(true);
    s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
    setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

    setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    // enable navigator.geolocation
    // s.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    // s.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/org.itri.html5webview/databases/");

    // enable Web Storage: localStorage, sessionStorage
    s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    mContentView.addView(this);
}

public HTML5WebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

public FrameLayout getLayout() {
    return mLayout;
}

public boolean inCustomView() {
    return (mCustomView != null);
}

public void hideCustomView() {
    mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if ((mCustomView == null) && canGoBack()){
            goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;
    private View        mVideoProgressView;

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
    {
        //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on ShowCustomView");
        HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }

        mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        System.out.println("nnn");
        if (mCustomView == null)
            return;

        // Hide the custom view.
        mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Remove the custom view from its container.
        mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
        mCustomView = null;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

        HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        HTML5WebView.this.goBack();
        //Log.i(LOGTAG, "set it to webVew");
    }


    @Override
    public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {
        //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on getVideoLoadingPregressView");

        if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_loading_progress, null);
        }
        return mVideoProgressView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
        ((Activity) mContext).setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, newProgress*100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}


static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS =
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

Comment: It seems this code doesn't work on **Oreo**, I tried it with **Marshmallow** and it works fine, I request to know why

Answer (score 1):

Try add this:

```
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` into activity tag in manifest